# jquery toggle classes after animation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have this javascript code: http://jsbin.com/orenim/4/edit

```
blinkTimes = 0;
function blink () {                           
  $('.a').toggleClass('b');
  blinkTimes --;
  if (blinkTimes > 0) {
    setTimeout(blink, 500);
  }
}

function startBlink() {
  //alert('?');
  blinkTimes = 4;
  blink();
}

$(document).click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: top }, '400', 'swing', startBlink);
});
```

This should toggle `'.b'` class right after animation. For some unknown reasons the `'.a'` element doesn't toggled with the class `'.b'`. If I uncomment the `alert('?')` the code is work.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('html, body')` selects two elements, firing two callbacks at the same time, which cancels each other out, try just `$('body').animate({ ....` and see how that works. If you need to select both elements, use a flag to make sure the callback function only runs once.

[**BIN**](http://jsbin.com/orenim/12/edit)

or as suggested by undefined, use a promise:

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: top }, '400', 'swing').promise().done(startBlink)
});
```

Comment: Yes, that true, one option is using `promise` and `done` methods.

Comment: @undefined - that's true, always forget promises when doing animations, and spend lots of time creating flags instead.